# Can't charge GoPro Hero 5 Black while recording TimeLapse video

Tags: gopro

I have a GoPro Hero 5 Black camera. I want to make timelapse videos with the default settings of TimeLapse video mode in the camera. I also want the camera plugged in since the time lapse will be running for a long time. If I connect the power cord before starting time lapse recording, it shows it is charging. However, once I start recording in time lapse mode, it stops charging.

Is it possible to record in time lapse mode and charge the camera at the same time? Do I need to change settings to enable this?

Comment: Have you verified that it runs out of power? It could be that it keeps drawing power from the power source even though it doesn't show that it is charging.